# How to handle code that does not return errors?

Tags: python, gis, arcpy

So I am writing some python scripts using ESRI's arcpy. I am inserting data into a db using . When all is well, i.e the object is created. If not, say the object already exists, nothing. No message, error, nothing. What are "best practices" for cases like this?

```
try:
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_feature_path, 'URN', 'text', 0, 0, 100,
                               field_alias = 'URN', 
                               field_is_nullable = "nullable", field_domain = '')
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

Code supplied above, I dont think I need it, but I always see people getting upset for not posting code :) .

Comment: Since no exception is being raised, look in the documentation and see if there's some way you can check beforehand if the object already exists. Another approach would be to check afterwards and see if it did what you wanted. It's also possible the `AddField_management()` function returns a value to indicate whether it succeeded or something like that.

Comment: Thanks martineau. The AddField_management function returns nothing. What we intend to do is to check if the field exists first. What I am looking for a different ways to handle situations like this.

Comment: In that case I suspect your only option is to check beforehand. Another idea: If `arcpy` is open source, you could also take a peek at the source code for the `AddField_management()` function and get some ideas...